# How to successfully upload local Wordpress configuration to Azure remote using All-In-One migration plugin

Tags: wordpress, azure

I am learning wordpress and i decided to play with Azure as well. I got a Wordpress app-service along a database up and running. I have also set up a local development environment using Local by Flywheel.

However, I am unable to upload my configuration to the Azure. After I have set up the local development environment, I have exported the remote config using [this](https://ro.wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/), only replacing the remote URL with the local URL used in development.

Once I have successfully imported it on my machine, I added some plugins and themes. When I was ready I exported the configuration again, this time by replacing the local URL with the remote URL. I went on the remote to import it, but after the proggress bar reaches 100%, in the console appears a javascript error.

```
VM364:1 POST https://<my-website>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=ai1wm_import 404 (Not Found)
(anonymous) @ VM364:1
send @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=5.2.4:4
ajax @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=5.2.4:4
FileUploader.upload @ import.min.js?v=7.9&ver=5.2.4:1358
(anonymous) @ import.min.js?v=7.9&ver=5.2.4:1246
dispatch @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=5.2.4:3
r.handle @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=5.2.4:3
import.min.js?v=7.9&ver=5.2.4:1384 Uncaught Error: error
    at Object.error (import.min.js?v=7.9&ver=5.2.4:1384)
    at i (load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=5.2.4:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as rejectWith] (load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=5.2.4:2)
    at x (load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=5.2.4:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.c (load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=5.2.4:4)
```

P.S. The upload limit is set to 512 Mb and the file has only 83Mbs. The timeout is set to 300 and it takes about 10 seconds for the bar to reach 100%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that it was a server-side issues as IIS was not allowing plugins to do large-scale updates, as well as as a dev issues, as the local development environment was using `ngnix`. I fixed this by simply creating a new `Wordpress` instace hosted on a linux machine using nginx. The upload worked flawlessly after that.